# How to pick the right nameserver

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver

Assuming the following structure:

- *example.com* registered in the United Staates (ISP 1)
- *example.ch* registered in Switzerland (ISP 2)
- *The server* registered in Switzerland (ISP 3)

Everyone of the 3 ISPs is offering their own nameservers to use (for any) TLD.

What criteria should be considered upon choosing the *best* nameserver in terms of response times?

Should I use **one** global nameserver for all domains (and if so: which one?), use every ISP's own nameserver for the respective domain? *Or is this question stupid?*

Comment: I added DNS as a tag, which is the heart of what you're asking about but isn't a term that you used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ideally, if this is a big concern, you would put DNS servers closest to the user population the site is intended for, so using local ISPs might be wisest. But there's a good argument for putting all the management for all of your DNS in a single place. You have to figure out what's going to work for you - there is no single "best" answer.

But this probably isn't a big concern. A bigger concern is what we call "diversity" - don't have *any* single one of those providers host *all* of the DNS servers for a given domain. Always have at least a secondary DNS server that is hosted somewhere with absolutely no connection to or dependency on the infrastructure of the primary DNS server. (Other than zone transfers of course.)

Because this is what happens when you do it wrong : http://www.wired.com/science/discoveries/news/2001/01/41412?currentPage=all

Comment: Thank you, that made the situation much more clear to me. So am I right to assume the following: 1. Client sends a request to the nameserver of his own ISP, 2. The nameserver responds with the address of my submitted nameserver list, 3. The Client asks the first server of the list. 4. If there is no response, the second nameserver is asked? I totally feel like missing the right keyword to google this..

Comment: You're missing recursion and a few other bits, but you're in the right neighborhood. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System#Address_resolution_mechanism http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772774(v=ws.10).aspx  http://www.cisco.com/web/about/security/intelligence/dns-bcp.html

Comment: Interesting link.  I didn't realise Microsoft made such a snafu with it's DNS design back then.